# Where are bitbake python functions documented

Tags: bitbake, yocto

I'm trying to find documentation for "bb.utils.contains".
I found the code in pokey/bitbake/lib/utils.py, but that code is poorly documented.
For instance, it takes a parameter named "d".  What is "d"?
How do you even get started with a short non-descriptive name like that?

I've downloaded and searched all the yocto and poky documents, and performed a number
of web searches, to no avail.

Does anybody know of a good reference to the built in bitbake python utilities?

Comment: I believe do is some sort of object that represents the environment of the bitbake recipe. It appears you can get and set variables (which would be the shell-looking variables in the .bb files). Aside from reading through the code I have no idea but would be interested to know.

Comment: Look here https://docs.yoctoproject.org/bitbake/2.0/singleindex.html

Answer (score 14):

The best documentation i could find were the docstrings in the code itself. See here: https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/blob/master/lib/bb/utils.py#L996

```
def contains(variable, checkvalues, truevalue, falsevalue, d):
    """Check if a variable contains all the values specified.
      Arguments:
        variable -- the variable name. This will be fetched and expanded (using
          d.getVar(variable, True)) and then split into a set().
        checkvalues -- if this is a string it is split on whitespace into a set(),
          otherwise coerced directly into a set().
        truevalue -- the value to return if checkvalues is a subset of variable.
        falsevalue -- the value to return if variable is empty or if checkvalues is
          not a subset of variable.
        d -- the data store.
    """
```

Answer (score 3):

'd' is the current dictionary of all the values being extracted from the environment and recipes.  See data.py and data_smart.py.

I agree the bitbake docs are not always complete, but there is a bitbake-dev mailing list that can help as well.